In a table in the action column I use an ellipse for more options. Should I change it for the edit and delete?
In a table I have an action column that has an ellipse icon with different options depending on which page you are on. In one table I will need an edit and delete option. Should I have these viewable in the table or place them in the ellipse keeping the pattern shown in the 1st image.?
I was thinking a solution would be to have the edit and delete displayed in the table beside the ellipse icon so they aren't hidden leaving the ellipse for other options.



The answer is 'it depends'.
I don't really know your use case from the small screenshots above, but here's a way of thinking on this.
Persistently visible
If you want be obvious at first glance, you can show the primary actions.
If you have the room in the table, it's a way of immediately showing the most important actions. Many icons are not universally understood, but edit and delete are much more likely to be encountered by users in a broad context of use.
If you don't want users guessing what's under the menu, consider this from LukeW, in 'obvious always wins'

In Sight, In Mind
When critical parts of an application are made more visible, usage of them can increase.

If these actions are important and save time and effort, put them in if they don't overwhelm the UI with visible noise (which in some cases they may).
All actions on hover (desktop only)
If you're designing for desktop, you can also surface all actions as a user hovers over a row. This can work when the table is likely to be a primary element and likely to be engaged as part of a workflow.
The other option you have already stated could still work, but context matters here.

Good link thanks. I agree. Kind looking for that validation "If these actions are important and save time and effort, put them in if they don't overwhelm the UI with visible noise (which in some cases they may)." Exactly
